# Should I explicitly dispose the Graphics object?

Tags: java, swing, awt

The javadoc said:

> For efficiency, programmers should call dispose when finished using a
>   Graphics object only if it was created directly from a component or
>   another Graphics object.

So in the following code, should I call `graphics.dispose()` before returning?
Or, can I?

```
{  ...  
BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(toWidth, toHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);  

java.awt.Graphics graphics=result.getGraphics();

graphics.drawImage(im.getScaledInstance(toWidth, toHeight, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH), 0, 0, null);  

return result;  
}
```

The `BufferedImage result` is returned and used elsewhere.

Comment: Since `result` and it's associated graphics object (`graphics`) go out of scope after the method call, I'd say yes.

Comment: Java returns Objects by reference. So if he disposes the graphics object, can he use it again for the returned object? I have no idea, maybe someone can answer this as well.

Comment: @Loki If he disposes it, he can't use it anymore.

Comment: @Kayaman, so he shouldn't dispose it in this method, as he returns the BufferedImage and may wants to use it later. Correct?

Comment: what are the results of disposing it in this method, and then calling `getGraphics()` again on the returned result?

Comment: Yes, the `result` is returned and used elsewhere.

Comment: @Loki No. He should dispose of the Graphics object, and if he wants to reuse it, get it again from the BufferedImage.

Comment: @Kayaman, yes I just realized that and posted a small example to show this behaviour

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Graphics` object can be disposed and should be disposed.

The `getGraphics` call of `BufferedImage` internally delegates to `createGraphics`, so there is no difference. The `createGraphics` call eventually delegates to the respective `GraphicsEnvironment` implementation, where (for the `SunGraphicsEnvironment`) it creates a **`new`** instance of a `SunGraphics2D`.

Finally, the `dispose` method of `SunGraphics2D` says the following:

```
  /**
   * This object has no resources to dispose of per se, but the
   * doc comments for the base method in java.awt.Graphics imply
   * that this object will not be useable after it is disposed.
   * So, we sabotage the object to prevent further use to prevent
   * developers from relying on behavior that may not work on
   * other, less forgiving, VMs that really need to dispose of
   * resources.
   */
  public void dispose() {
      surfaceData = NullSurfaceData.theInstance;
      invalidatePipe();
  }
```

which also gives a *justification* of why `dispose` indeed *should* be called (even if it is not strictly necessary in the default implementations)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedImage img = get();

        Graphics g = img.getGraphics();

        //g.drawOval(5, 5, 5, 5); //this statement will work (you'll see the cirle)

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            ImageIO.write( img, "jpg", baos );

            baos.flush();
            byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
            baos.close();

            Files.write(Paths.get("test2.png"), imageInByte);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static BufferedImage get(){
        BufferedImage res = new BufferedImage(50, 50, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics g = res.getGraphics();

        g.drawRect(0, 0, 20, 20);

        g.dispose();

        g.drawOval(5, 5, 5, 5); //this statement won't work, you'll only see the rect

        return res;
    }


}
```

As you can see, you can savely (and should) dispose the `graphics` in your method.

You can't use the graphics object in the method afterwards, so when you run the code, there won't be a circle in the picture. But if you comment out `g.drawOval(5,5,5,5)` in the method, but comment in the same statement in the `main`-Method, you will see a circle. So you can use it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Because due to JavaDoc `getGpahics()` method forwards to `createGraphics()` you should dispose the Graphics object at the end of your method.